# get notifications when kafka producer is online or offline

Tags: java, swing, apache-kafka

I'm building a website using springboot as RestAPI and angular in frontend. Also, i will be getting data in  my rest(consumer) from around 40-50 swing standalone apps(producers) through kafka. I need to implement online status for those swing apps. Basically, i need to know when and which one of swing apps went offline or back online. Is there a way to implement this? If this is impossible with kafka can you recommend something else for communication?

Clarification:
By online status i mean whether device on which swing app is installed has internet connection or not.
Swing app will be installed on around 40-50 devices on remote locations.

Comment: What defines "online"? Certainly you should use some external tool built with the purpose of healthchecks like Nagios, for example?

Comment: Well, in my case, online as whether app has internet connection or not. I need to process that information in rest. Like notification that certain app lost or regained internet connection. Is this possible with Nagios?

Comment: You do mean „***Swing** apps*“ like you said. Right? And not „***Spring** apps* “?

Comment: Yes, i mean swing apps. To clarify, it will be the same swing app installed on 40-50 devices on remote locations.

Comment: Nagios (or simlar monitoring tool) can run simple scripts. Of which, could `ping 8.8.8.8`, for example... Kafka seems very much overkill for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually i got rid of kafka and used websockets. Using [WebSocketHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/WebSocketHandler.html) i had information when certain standalone app is connected or disconnected. When standalone app looses internet connection server is notified relatively quickly (within 60 seconds). Keep in mind that in my case standalone app will be sending data quite often. If this is not the case for you then i recommend looking for some other solutions and taking a look at @OneCriketeer comment regarding Nagios.